# MVC3 routing not working after deployment on IIS7.5

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-3

After creating a Web Application project in VS2010, adding a routing route and run in debug mode the routing seems to work properly and I have no problem.

But when I tried to deploy it on IIS7.5 on my local machine, and tried to click a link that uses routing it throws:
"HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Does anyone encountered the same issue?

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: @czetsuya, I have this problem too, and have been tearing my hair out all afternoon with no solution in site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolved this issue and document on how I did it here:

http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-deploy-mvc3-powered-website-to.html

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you are missing the module for UrlRouting.

1. Go to the site in IIS
2. Click on Modules
3. Look for an module of type: System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule(in my IIS the name is UrlRoutingModule-4.0)
4. If you can't find it click "Add Managed Module" and paste the information in last step. Also check the checkbox.

I hope that helps. If that isn't the problem check if you are running under Integrated mode(Look at the App pool for that application).

Comment: Thanks for the reply it works now, I've deleted and created a new virtual directory but not under Integrated mode. Not really sure what I did wrong in the first try.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I do have the routing module installed.  I didn't have to install it, it was always there.

Comment: This was not installed by default in IIS 8 on windows 2012.